# Why does PyCharm add spaces after strings?

Tags: python, string, pycharm

When I copy commands into PyCharm spaces are added before `'`.

```py
path1 = str(path_onc ) +'/derivatives/participant/fmriprep/sub- ' +str(counter ) +'/ses-1/func/ ' +str(folder_rh)
```

How can I tell PyCharm not to do so?

Comment: Do you mean spaces around the `+` operator or spaces inside string literals before closing `'`? The first ones are added to adhere to PEP8, try **Edit | Paste | Paste as Plain Text** if you prefer no formatting to be applied. The second ones are quite surprising, I can see no reason for PyCharm to insert such spaces nor do I know IDE features to automatically alter string literals unless there is some language injection. Your best bet in the second case is to contact PyCharm support at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.